# MultiLabelBinarizer returning a null matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I created a `MultiLabelBinarizer` with classes as tags, `keys()` as classes.
But the returned `y_train` and `y_val` matrices are returned as null.

I tried the following code.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(classes=sorted(tags_counts.keys()))
y_train = mlb.fit_transform(y_train)
y_val = mlb.fit_transform(y_val)
```

Expected a converted features table, got a null one instead.

Comment: classes=sorted(tags_counts.keys()) problem is here you need to show code

Comment: @AnkushRasgon Hi, I actually thought the same, and printed it separately.
It gave the correct results, I matched it with the training data and it doesn't have an error.